# How to enter this equation in latex?

Tags: equations

[image]

How to enter this equation in latex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
H^{l+1} = \sigma\Biggl( \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{A} \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} H^l W^l \Biggr)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

To reduce the size of the parentheses (which are unnecessarily big), you could replace `\Biggl` and `\Biggr` with `\bigl` and `\bigr`, which seem to be more appropriate here.

Comment: The parentheses are really unnecessarily big.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Yes I agree, I just tried to replicate the OP's picture. Anyway, I added a comment about this, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 3):

You really should take advantage of a beginner's guide, see [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/)

Split the problem into parts. You have letters with an exponent and others with a decoration and an exponent.

For a letter with an exponent, the LaTeX way is

```
a^{b}
```

(a subscript would be `a_{b}` and you can combine both in either order). The decoration is a tilde and the syntax is

```
\tilde{a}
```

The Greek letter is a (lowercase) sigma and you input it as `\sigma`.

A two-story fraction is input as `\frac{a}{b}`.

It remains the problem of the parentheses that, in the picture you show are obnoxiously big for no reason. So the first try would be

```
H^{l+1}=\sigma(\tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{A} \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} H^{l} W^{l})
```

quite likely in a displayed equation. You might consider the simple parentheses too small in the particular case, because of the decorations and the high exponents, so you may try `\big` size:

```
H^{l+1}=\sigma \bigl( \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{A} \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} H^{l} W^{l} \bigr)
```

In the minimal document below, both are shown.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
H^{l+1}=\sigma(\tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{A} \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} H^{l} W^{l})
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
H^{l+1}=\sigma \bigl( \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} \tilde{A} \tilde{D}^{-\frac{1}{2}} H^{l} W^{l} \bigr)
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Personally, I'd go with the top one: parentheses are delimiters that denote, in this case, the argument to a function. You reader expects them and will see them. They're not blankets that must cover the entire thing.

Note `\bigl` for the opening (left) parenthesis and `\bigr` for the closing (right) parenthesis.

The next size, `\Big` (with `\Bigl(` and `\Bigr)`) would be too large

[image]

and there's no reason to do like this. The fact that such big fences are seen in papers on the net is not a reason. You'll find that somebody recommends `\left(` and `\right)`. The result would be

[image]

which is even worse. It uses `\Big` size, but also adds an undesired horizontal space that hinders understanding the meaning.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb}

\begin{document}

  \[ H^{l + 1} = \sigma\Bigl( \widetilde{D}{}^{-\frac 12}\widetilde{A}\,\widetilde{D}{}^{-\frac 12}H^{l}W^{l}\Bigr) \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Are the `{}` empty math atoms needed? Aside: do also replace `σ` with `\sigma`. :-)

Comment: @Mico: I used `{}` to avoid having the exponent too high (because of the tilde). As to \sigma, it's a problem with my editor; I configured WinEdt so that greek ketters appear as they look on a printed page, but they're saved as the latex command, and I forgot to check this point in my answer. 'Tis fixed now. Thanks for pointing the problem!